# Facebook SDK returned an error: Connection timed out after 10001 milliseconds

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i have integrated facebook login (PHP Sdk Version 5.0.0) with my website. That is working fine in my localhost. But it shows the following error when i have hosted in my server;

> Facebook SDK returned an error: Connection timed out after 10001
>   milliseconds

I have just changed the 'Site URL' and 'OAuth redirect URI' only when i hosted in server. Is it necessary to change anything else in my app? I have checked curl is enabled in my server, its showing 'enabled' in php ini. My PHP Version is 5.5.28.

My code is given below;

index.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$path = realpath(dirname(__FILE__));

require $path .'/facebook-sdk-v5/autoload.php';

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id' => 'xxxxxxx',
    'app_secret' => 'xxxxxxxx',
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.4',
        ]);

$helper = $fb->getCanvasHelper();

// Grab the signed request entity
$sr = $helper->getSignedRequest();

// Get the user ID if signed request exists
$user = $sr ? $sr->getUserId() : null;

if ($user)
{
    try
    {
        // Get the access token
        $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
    }
    catch (Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e)
    {
        // There was an error communicating with Graph
        echo $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }
}
else
{
    $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

    $permissions = ['public_profile','email','user_birthday','user_location']; // optional
    $callback = 'http://www.example.com/ret_page.php';
    $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl($callback, $permissions);

    echo '<a href="' . $loginUrl . '">Log in with Facebook!</a>';


}
```

ret_page.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$path = realpath(dirname(__FILE__));
require $path .'/facebook-sdk-v5/autoload.php';

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id' => 'xxxxxx',
    'app_secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.4',
        ]);

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

try
{
    $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
}
catch (Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e)
{
    // When Graph returns an error
    echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}
catch (Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e)
{
    // When validation fails or other local issues
    echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}

if (!isset($accessToken))
{
    if ($helper->getError())
    {
        header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
        echo "Error: " . $helper->getError() . "\n";
        echo "Error Code: " . $helper->getErrorCode() . "\n";
        echo "Error Reason: " . $helper->getErrorReason() . "\n";
        echo "Error Description: " . $helper->getErrorDescription() . "\n";
    }
    else
    {
        header('HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request');
        echo 'Bad request';
    }
    exit;
}

// Logged in
echo '<h3>Access Token</h3>';
var_dump($accessToken->getValue());

$fb->setDefaultAccessToken($accessToken);
$res    = $fb->get('/me?fields=id,name,gender,email,birthday,location');
$user   = $res->getGraphObject();

// Printing result
print_r($user);
```

Comment: Let me see your code!

Comment: @Luïs , My code is added.

Comment: @Luis, This code is working fine with localhost. But in server, it shows ;

Facebook SDK returned an error: Connection timed out after 10001 milliseconds